# Excel VBA: Select the column next to the column with data and then insert 3 columns

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub New
ActiveSheet.Range(“c9”).End(xlRight).Offset(1,0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:xlToRight
End Sub
```

This doesn't work at all and gives me an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You should expound..."Doesn't work at all and gives an error" without describing what you wanted it to do or the error given doesn't allow anyone to help.

Comment: You have "smart quotes"  around `c9` instead of regular ones.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I'm trying to add a column next to the last column of data. My code was trying to first find the last part of data in a certain row and then add columns beside it.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your entire code with 1 line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).EntireColumn.Insert
```

The first part `ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Offset(0, 1)` you select the cell on the right side of Cell "C9".

The second part `.Resize(, 3).EntireColumn.Insert` you insert 3 columns at once on the right side (instead of repeating the same line 3 times)

In case you meant to find the last column in row 9 with data, as in `Range("C9").End(xlRight)`, use the code below:

```
With ActiveSheet
    ' find last column with data in row 9
    LastColumn = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .Range(Cells(9, LastColumn), Cells(9, LastColumn)).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).EntireColumn.Insert
End With
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping! That's exactly what I needed! Thank you!