# Finding last column and adding formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data with a dynamic range of columns. Sometimes more columns can be added and sometimes there could be less.

Overall, I am trying to find the last column of data used in the table via excel Vba (ie column ab) , take the next column (ac)  and input a formula in ac 2 i.e =sum[amount].

Does anyone have any suggestions to help?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried anything?  (If none of the existing answers in Stack Overflow helped, I'm not sure what else to suggest.)

Comment: [Finding the last column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926972/excel-vba-finding-the-last-column-with-data), [Selecting the next column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661052/excel-vba-select-the-column-next-to-the-column-with-data-and-then-insert-3-colu), [Set the formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367947/vba-set-excel-formula-containing-quotation-marks-as-cell-value)

Comment: When you say table, do you mean your data is in an Excel Table i.e. formatted as structured excel table?